# Issue with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, umbraco

I am currently trying to obtain some json information to add for a dashboard within razorflow. So i have created the HTTPGet method for the Umbraco this method deffinitely works however i believe it is a problem with the jquery ajax.

Below is the current code:

```
function addDatabaseDiagnostic(kpiobject, endpoint, name) {

    kpiobject.addKPI(name, {
        caption: name,
        value: 0,
        numberSuffix: " ms"
    });



    $.ajax({
        url: baseDiagUrl + endpoint,
        type: 'GET',
        Accept : "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*",
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            kpiobject.updateKPI(name, {
                value: data['ElapsedMilliseconds'],
            });
        },
        error: function (data) {
            debugger;
            kpiobject.updateKPI(name, {
                value: data,
            });
        }
    });
```

The function should get the information from the website and be able to insert this into the field.

I have been using 'Fiddler' and this is saying that the Get method has Occured, and is working however it is going straight into the Error part of the function. Any help will be greatly recieved and if you need more information I shall try to give you it.

Thanks

Comment: Are u sure it is 'Accept' not 'accept'?

Comment: What is returned in the `data` passed in to your error function?

Comment: @Turtle It's `accepts` I believe.

Comment: It seems that your url is incorrect, or unavailable, so it results in error.

Comment: @Turtle  Hello I have tried both of these and both of these return the same issue. It doesn't happen to get into the success function. The url should be correct, and the data doesn't bring in anything i believe it just uses that later which is the 'elapsed milliseconds' diagnostic

Answer (score 0):

The issue with this was the web.config file. The website wasn't allowing the JSON headers, so thus is why it was returning null. (undefined) by adding a couple of lines to allow the azure website to allow this information to be retrieved this then resolved the issue and I am now getting the required output. Thanks for your help.